# Keep image from stretching in div and keeping scale

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get images to keep the same ratio when they are placed in a div, next to text.

This is what it currently looks like. As you can see the images are stretched to how high the div is that contains the text next to it.

[image]

This is the HTML:

```
<body>

   <div id="content" class="content">
      <div id="title" class="title">
         Sports
      </div>
      <nav class="nav_bar">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./sports.html">Sport</a></li>
            <li><a href="./academics.html">Academics</a></li>
            <li><a href="./other.html">Other</a></li>
            <li><a href="./stats.html">Stats</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      <div id="page_description" class="page_description">
         One of my main objectives for the first term of university was to get back my fitness. I decided to do this through going to the gym and playing futsal.
      </div>
      <div id="gym" class="main_container">
         <!-- Title, Hours, Description -->
         <div class="other_div">
            <div class="activity_title_hours">
               <div class="activity_title">
                  The Gym 
               </div>
               <div class="activity_hours">
                  - 5 Hours
               </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="hr_title_divider">
            <div class="activity_description">
               <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ultrices mauris ante consequat fusce adipiscing, tempor orci aliquam, eros rutrum gravida nec, quo augue lectus integer consequat. Vitae quis fringilla erat nunc ligula habitant. Tortor risus aliquam sodales 
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Pic -->
         <div id="pic_container" class="pic_container">
            <img src="./images/gym.jpeg" class="pic" alt="The Gym logo"/>
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="hr_divider">
      <div id="5-aside" class="main_container">
         <!-- Title, Hours, Description -->
         <div class="other_div">
            <div class="activity_title_hours">
               <div class="activity_title">
                  5 Aside Footy
               </div>
               <div class="activity_hours">
                  - 5 Hours
               </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="hr_title_divider">
            <div class="activity_description">
               <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ultrices mauris ante consequat fusce adipiscing, tempor orci aliquam, eros rutrum gravida nec, quo augue lectus integer consequat. Vitae quis fringilla erat nunc ligula habitant. Tortor risus aliquam sodales  
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Pic -->
         <div id="pic_container" class="pic_container">
            <img src="./images/5-aside.jpeg" class="pic" alt="5 Aside"/>
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="hr_divider">
   </div>
</body>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.page_description {
    background-color:rgba(555,555,555,0.5);
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: large;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.main_container {
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    background-color:rgba(555,555,555,0.5);
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: flex;
    /* margin-bottom: 5%; */
}

.other_div {
    float: left;
    min-width: 60%;
    max-width: 60%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.activity_title_hours{
    display: flex;
}

.activity_title {
    float: left;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    height: 100%;
    /* width: 50%; */
    line-height: 40px;
}

.activity_hours {
    float: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    min-height: 100%;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: left;
}

.pic {
    float: right;
    /* min-width: 35%; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
}



.activity_description p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

hr {
    border-width: 2px;
}
.hr_tag {
    width:40%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.hr_divider {
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 3px;
    color: white;
    background-color: white;
    border: none
}

.hr_title_divider {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 3px;
    color: white;
    background-color: white;
    border: none
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    color: white;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

How can I stop the images from stretching like they currently do?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any CSS for pic_container div in the sample you posted. Is there any CSS for that? Your pic class is set to 100% height and width of its container, so that could be stretching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your rule for `.pic`, change `height: 100%;` to `height: auto;`

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much! Will accept it as the answer when I can